# How to get checkstate and checkbox.text from different Class

Tags: c#, text, if-statement, checkbox, listbox

i need your help again.. i doing this program that if the checkbox from Form2.cs is checked then i will clicked a button to show another WindowsForm(another Form.cs) that has a listbox that will show a the text from that checkbox. here is my work on the other form.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class computationOfDineIn : Form
    {

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();

        public computationOfDineIn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (form2.checkBox1.Checked)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(form2.checkBox1.Text.ToString());

            }


        }


    }
}
```

i change the modifier of the checkbox in Form2.cs to Public so i can use it in another form. but it doesn't work, am I missing somehthing? please somebody tell me. `(Q. how can i make it appear in the listbox from another form when the conditions is met?)` I knmow this is a silly question but thank you in advance!!! :D

**update: code on where Form2 is shown.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();


            form2.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 form3 = new Form3();
            form3.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you show form2?

Comment: form2.show(); i use this in a button... just like the other form

Comment: post that code. Whether you use same `form2` or different instance?

Comment: downvoted... without reason??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're creating new instance of `Form2` inside `computationOfDineIn`. You should use the same instance of form2 which you show to user.

And making the UI elements public is not the recommended way. IMO you've to create a property which says whether the checkbox is checked or not.

You need to save the `form2` instance somewhere and somehow you need to pass the instance to `computationOfDineIn` form then check the property in that instance.

One way is to pass it through constructor.

```
public partial class computationOfDineIn : Form
{
    Form2 form2 = null;

    public computationOfDineIn(Form2 form2)//pass the form2 you created in button click
    {
        this.form2 = form2;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```